# Updating local ColdFusion variable in Ajax

Tags: coldfusion-11

I have been trying to perform a simple task (in ASP) for a coldfusion page. I have a local variable "pt.PreCaution" that I need updated. I have tried the following code with no success.

```
       <cfset pt.PreCaution = "">


        <label>
            Patient Precaution:
        </label>
        <br>
        <cfselect name="lstPreCaution" multiple="yes"
        query="GetPreCaution" 
        value="IsoTypeID" 
        display="IsoTypeName"
        size="8"
        required="yes"
        width="100"
        height="25"
        label="Precaution: "
        onclick="PreCautionSelected(this)"
        >
        </cfselect>


 function PreCautionSelected(val){
 var result ="";
 var frm=eval('document.next');

for(i = 0 ; i < val.children.length; i++)
{
    if(val.children[i].selected){
        if(result.length < 1)
        {
            result = val.children[i].value;
        }
        else
        {
            result = result + "," + val.children[i].value;
        }
    }
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "details.cfm",
    data: { "#pt.PreCaution#" : result}
}).done(function(){alert(result)})
```

}

I modified the ajax call as follows:

```
function PreCautionSelected(val){
    var result ="";
    var frm=eval('document.next');

    for(i = 0 ; i < val.children.length; i++)
    {
        if(val.children[i].selected){
            if(result.length < 1)
            {
                result = val.children[i].value;
            }
            else
            {
                result = result + "," + val.children[i].value;
            }
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FileUpdater.cfc?method=setPrecautionType",
        data: { lstPrecaution : result}
    }).done(function(){})


}

<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="setPrecautionType" access="remote" returntype="Any" >
        <cfargument name="lstPrecaution" type="any" required="true" >
        <cfset  session.lstPreCaution = #arguments.lstPrecaution#>
        <cfreturn />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

I added the following CFC file. This file updates the session variables.

CFC File

Comment: The wording of your question is a bit confusing...  A) Can you elaborate on what you mean by "no success"? If you are getting an error, please [edit] your post to include the full error message. B)  It sounds like you are trying to POST a variable *from* an ASP page *to* a ColdFusion page, ie "details.cfm". Is that correct? C) Why do you think you need to populate a variable named `pt.PreCaution`? That seems unlikely as POST values usually end up in the FORM scope of the receiving page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. The Ajax function is getting called and the complete data is being extracted. The only problem is the ColdFusion variable is not getting updated on the server side.

I fixed this problem by written the data to the session data. The problem is the old CF5 frame work that the program is written in.

Comment: Could you elaborate with a few more details  and/or a code snippet showing how the problem was resolved to help the next guy?

Answer (score -1):

You have only one mistake.select box not have onclick functionality so you have onchange function means working fine

Comment: Your answer is a little confusing. You might want to consider editing it.